# Write localized string to localized file

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, file-io, localization

I have the following piece of code:

```
Dim fecha As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(fichero.Text)
    w.WriteLine(fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + vbTab + tiempo.Text + vbTab + comentario.Text)
    w.Close()
End Using
```

Which is called from a Windows Form in .NET 4, where *tiempo* and *comentario* are two TextBox where you get strings. The problem I have is that if I write a localized phrase with apostrophes, they appear as "Ã³" "Ã©" or "Ã­-" in the text file instead of "ó" "é" and "í".

Any idea how can I set the function to write correctly the localized phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `File.AppendText` you can create a new `StreamWriter` and specify whatever encoding you like. For example 1252 for Latin (Western European languages). 2'nd parameter specifies that the text should be appended to the file.

```
Using writer = New StreamWriter(fichero.Text, True, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
    writer.WriteLine(fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + vbTab + tiempo.Text + vbTab + comentario.Text)
End Using
```

Also disposing the writer will call `Close` (no need to explicitly call it)

Comment: Thanks, changed the code to `Using w As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fichero.Text, True, Encoding.Unicode)` and worked without problem.